# how to use js simulation input those <div contenteditable ="true"> elements.thanks

Tags: javascript

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 509px;" id="test"></div>

document.getElementById("test").value=1231
document.getElementById("test").innerText=1231
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=1231
```

None of the above methods worked when I hit the submit button.

I wonder if I have to trigger events to save values

But I don't know how to create event

The belows methods works in inputs evets ,but not work in

```
<input type="text" id="test2">

window.inputValue(document.getElementById("test2"),"simulation_string")

window.inputValue = function (dom, st) {
    var evt = new InputEvent('input', {
        inputType: 'insertText',
        data: st,
        dataTransfer: null,
        isComposing: false
    });
    dom.value = st;
    dom.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: Is there another solution? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in your code as you've not added the closing double quote for the `style` attribute.

Next, a `div` element does not have a `value` property and when you want to set content into it, that content must be a string.

Also, when setting the value of an element as a non-HTML string, use `.textContent`.

Finally, you imply that you will be submitting data, which will only work with `form` fields. A `div` is not a form field, so you'll have to copy the contents of the `div` into another element that will submit its data along with the rest of the form. Or, you could just use a `textarea` in the first place instead of a `div`.

```js
document.getElementById("test").textContent = "1231";

// Copy the div content into the hidden form field so that it will transmit
document.getElementById("divData").value = document.getElementById("test").textContent;

console.log(document.getElementById("divData").value);
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 509px;" id="test"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="divData">
```

Comment: Thanks. What I want to realize is to simulate input string .but wahterer .value .html .textContent .they just change the  value of the surface . it didn't Trigger the event of web page JS to save the value.you can see the example above .when it <input> it works. but not work in div. in fact. what i want to do is simulate sending message on facebook .but its "input" are not <input> but <div contenteditable="true"> .it's a big problem. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMmtb.png